# Issue generating ruby scaffolding

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, scaffolding

so I have set up my database and trying to generate some scaffolding for the app I made. I get this error, and I am a bit confused. Any advice? Thanks!

```
rails generate scaffold product title:string description:text image_url:string
/Users/Cameron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:203:in `parse': (<unknown>): could not find expected ':' while scanning a simple key at line 18 column 3 (Psych::SyntaxError)
from /Users/Cameron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:203:in `parse_stream'
from /Users/Cameron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:151:in `parse'
from /Users/Cameron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:127:in `load'
from /Users/Cameron/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:115:in `database_configuration'
from /Users/Cameron/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:78:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
from /Users/Cameron/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
from /Users/Cameron/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
from /Users/Cameron/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `block in run_load_hooks'
from /Users/Cameron/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `each'
from /Users/Cameron/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `run_load_hooks'
from /Users/Cameron/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/base.rb:720:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/Cameron/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:88:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
from /Users/Cameron/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
from /Users/Cameron/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
from /Users/Cameron/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
from /Users/Cameron/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
from /Users/Cameron/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
from /Users/Cameron/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
from /Users/Cameron/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
from /Users/Cameron/depot/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/Cameron/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require'
from /Users/Cameron/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
from /Users/Cameron/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:25:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Can you show your config database file: config/database.yml ?

Answer (score 4):

This is likely a problem in your `config/database.yml` file.  The error is from Psych, which is Ruby's YAML parsing engine.  I don't know of any other YAML files that are read during a `rails g scaffold`, and I can reproduce that failure by introducing a typo into my `database.yml` file.

There are some [online YAML validators](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/) you can paste your file into for help debugging it.  Or add it to your question above if you can't find the problem.

Comment: You're the best. I was missing a space on my password entry :. The learning goes on! Thanks